# Find if the given size of the rectangle fits on the rectangle

Tags: rectangles

Given a rectangle of size row = 3 and col = 2 which are occupied by other rectangles as in figure.
[image]

The shaded region in green are occupied.

Now what I want to find is, if a rectangle of size (p = 2 and q = 1) or (p = 2 and q=2) can be placed on the empty slots of the rectangle without using any iterations.

[image]

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$?

Comment: that is the size of another rectangle to be fitted.

Comment: So the occupied rectangles are arbitrary, both in number and position in the grid?

Comment: yes, they are arbitrary.